# Return Integers in Base 10

Tags: c#, radix

I've been trying to understand how one would input an integer and have a function return the digits in base 10 in C#. I've researched around and can't find many code examples to work with other than the math formulas.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean? please give an example..

Comment: into base 10? I think we need more information. Integers are already in base 10!

Comment: @MementoMori: No, integers are just numbers. The concept of a base only applies when you convert them into a string.

Comment: You would use one of the predefined formatting functions provided by the standard library, such as this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx

Comment: Heh I know theyre in base 10, but I want the function to return and output that. So, if the user inputs an integer, it will break down the base 10 of that integer.

Comment: @user2163879: What do you mean by "break down the base 10"? Are you *actually* just looking for a string representation, as per my answer? If not, you need to be clearer about what you want - and I suspect you may not even be clear about it in your mind yet. You should at least be able to write the method *signature*, even if you don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
int value = 2590123;
string text = value.ToString();
```

That will automatically use base 10... at least in all the cultures I'm aware of. If you really want to make sure, use the invariant culture:

```
string text = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that the concept of a base only makes sense when you talk about some representation with separate "digits" of some form - such as a string representation. A pure *number* doesn't have a base - if you have 16 apples, that's the same number as if you've got 0x10 apples.

EDIT: Or if you want to write a method to return the sequence of digits as integers, least significant first:

```
// Note that this won't give pleasant results for negative input
static IEnumerable<int> GetDigits(int input)
{
    // Special case...
    if (input == 0)
    {
        yield return 0;
        yield break;
    }
    while (input != 0)
    {
        yield return input % 10;
        input = input / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: (While it's certainly good practice to use `InvariantCulture` where appropriate, I once ran a loop over all cultures on my PC, and all of them returned the same result for integers. So it doesn't really have an effect in practice.)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Though they won't return the same results if you ask for a thousands separator.  Culture is not always irrelevant to number formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Making a whole lot of assumptions, I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
// All ints are "base 10"
var thisIsAlreadyBase10 = 10;
Console.WriteLine("The number {0} in base 10 is {0}", thisIsAlreadyBase10);

// However, if you have a string with a non-base 10 number...
var thisHoweverIsAStringInHex = "deadbeef";
Console.WriteLine(
    "The hex string {0} == base 10 int value {1}", 
    thisHoweverIsAStringInHex, 
    Convert.ToInt32(thisHoweverIsAStringInHex, 16));
```